# Appending various strings between two delimeters in one string. python

Tags: python, string, delimiter

I've been stuck here a day. So I thought to ask the experts.
I am reading contents from a file which has data in form

```
|something|
|something else|
|something_1
 something_2
 someting_3|
|something blah blah|
```

.. and so on..
so as you guys figured it out.. the delimiter is '|'
now.. I want the output in following form
|something|
|something else|
|something_1_something_2_someting_3|
|something blah blah|
basically everything between a delimiter in one string
Any clues how to go about it
Programming language is Python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re
print re.findall(r"\|[^|]*\|", text)
```

If you haven't seen this before, its a regular expression. Basically you describe a pattern in text that you are looking for. I recommend reading up on it if you don't know them.

Comment: `[s.replace('\n ', '_') for s in re.findall(r"\|[^|]*\|", text)]` for the desired output

Comment: hi.. this is my code.. but its not working as of now..def readProductDescriptionFile(filename):
    #print" helo here"
    # If this is empty, then exit with an error
    if ""==filename:
        return []

    text = ""    
    try:
        with open(filename, 'r') as f:
            lines=f.readlines()
    except IOError as (errno, strerror):
        print "I/O error({0}): {1}".format(errno, strerror),filename
        return []
        
    for lines in re.findall(r"\|[^|]*\|", text):    

        line = lines.replace('\n','_')
        print line

Comment: @Fraz, please edit your question to include the code as I can't make sense of it without the newlines. Also clearly describe what it does and what you expect it to do.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're making this too complicated for yourself. The way you've described your output format, it seems like all you really need to do is put everything on one line. If I'm right about this, you can read all of the data in as a string (as long as the file isn't too large), remove newline characters ('\n' or '\r\n' depending on your system) and write this out to a file. Alternatively, if you want to be more memory efficient you can iterate through the file line by line (my recommended solution).

If I was mistaken about your output format, comment here and I'll help you out with that. I didn't provide any code because this is something you can easily find in the Python documentation (i.e. string methods, file I/O).

Comment: Hi.Thanks for the response.so the data is in the following format |5|1|Celestine 8x10|-|&lt;p&gt;A dense silk floral arabesque in powder blue stands out against the beige wool ground of this rug, which recalls the organic swirls and nature motifs common to Art Nouveau. It may look like something your grandmother once had, but it couldn't be fresher. &lt;/p&gt;  In some lines this entry can go into multiple lines. so there are many data lines like this.so I want to parse these data to the existing datastructure.the way i have tokenize this requires everything between the delimiter in one string